# getline won't read string from a variable. (C++)

Tags: c++, string, file-io, getline

I'm trying to make a variable store a written question which will then be written to a file however, the string is not being read by the getline and when I try to write it to the file it simply writes nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

void addquestiontofile(){
    ofstream myfile;
    // Open file to be written to.
    myfile.open("quesitons.txt",ios::ate | ios::app);

    string newquestion;
    cout << "insert new question:  \n";
    getline(cin, newquestion); // This is the problem line

    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << newquestion;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the code look like where you call this function?  It doesn't happen to contain something like this: `cin >> something;` Does it?

Comment: Have you read anything else from `cin` before this? You may have the end of a previous input line in its buffer, especially if you used `>>` to read something.

Comment: Your example code looks fine to me. Maybe flush the output file just to be safe? Like this: `myfile << newquestion << flush;`

Comment: Compiled and executed fine on VS2010 (`int main() { addquestiontofile(); return 0; }`.

Comment: Your example compiles and runs (after adding a main function) fine for me, and whatever I enter, it gets written to the file. Are you sure that it writes nothing? maybe you are just looking wrong at the file, try with a hexeditor, or try putting some endline after the output.

Comment: Are you counting lines in "questions.txt" to determine if anything was written? As there will not be any as no newline characters are written.

Comment: Does `myfile.is_open()` return `true`? it will be unknown to you if the open failed as no failure message is printed to report this.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I used cin to get a select case, in my main function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, how? I though `~ofstream()` closed the underlying file, and therefore flushed the buffer.

Comment: @hmjd: Yes, it does.  Something's fishy. If his problem was fixed when he did that, I have a feeling he did something else besides that too.  Like modifying his main function.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it sounds like you have used `cin >> variable` to read from a previous line of input. This will leave the end of that previous line in the input stream's buffer, so the next call to `getline()` will yield an empty string.

You can clear the remainder of the line with

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a trailing newline from a previous input.  Try this:

```
while (newquestion.empty())
{
    getline(cin, newquestion);
    boost::trim(newquestion);
}
```